# Paste numbers as string

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have one spreadsheet in Google Sheets with data like:

```
0012
0234
0065
```

I want to paste this in another Google Sheets but when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> the data is formatted like numbers:

```
12
234
65
```

I want conserve the string format.

With right-click copy-paste I can't copy between spreadsheets.

Tested in Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: Very strange... Edit>Copy and Edit>Paste do not actually copy/paste anything between spreadsheets! Yet the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V (which are allocated to these menu items) do copy the values, but lose all formatting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a single quote (`'`) in front of the zeros before you copy the cells.

If you need to apply this to lots of cells, set the contents of one cell to `'` and use `CONCAT` to populate a new column with the `'` and the cell contents.

If A1 is `'` and the values you want to copy start in B1:

Set C1 to `=CONCAT($A$1, $B1)` and fill the formula down.

Comment: this doesn't work if the numbers have leading 0s due to the number format of the cells :/

Comment: Well, maybe it did 8 years ago lol. Now the copy/paste works for that, but in case someone else stumble here because they wanted to concat the number with a string and still have the leading 0s, you can do '=TEXT($B1, "0000")'.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I see: press <kbd>'</kbd> before pasting. It will preserve string format.

Pasting in the same spreadsheet preserves formatting. Pasting into another, says `Pasting from web clipboard...`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found a good solution.

Copy the table to some simple text editor that supports regex. I used notepad++. Then insert the decimal separator before the numbers. Then you can copy the table to the spreadsheet.

E.g. if you have 3 digits without a decimal separator in front, you search replace using `(\d\d\d)` and `.\1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another method that worked. Just save the file to a CSV format. Close and reopen the file, but choose to format columns as text. I have done it with Libre Office.

Answer (score -1):

1. copy the cells using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. go to the target spreadsheet
3. highlight the cells you want to paste them on
4. go to `FORMAT > NUMBERS >`  and click `PLAIN TEXT` at the bottom
   (this formats the cells to text fields before you paste)
5. paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the cells

Comment: This don't work, neither Firefox nor Chromium

Comment: If it didn't work before, it works now. I pasted a large sheet of data from LibreOffice Calc into a Google Sheet, then selected the entire column that contained the broken numeric strings, pasted again over the top of the existing data and the leading zeroes were back.